# VB script to send emails - Wait until email is send

Tags: email, vbscript

I use the below VB script to send emails. When I execute it from the command prompt it returns to the command prompt after execution. If there are any error while sending, a pop up message is shown.

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count <> 6 then
 Wscript.Echo "Missing parameters"
Else
 Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
 objMessage.Subject = Wscript.Arguments(0) 
 objMessage.From = Wscript.Arguments(1) 
 objMessage.To = Wscript.Arguments(2) 
 objMessage.TextBody = Wscript.Arguments(3)
 objMessage.AddAttachment Wscript.Arguments(4)
 objMessage.AddAttachment Wscript.Arguments(5)
 objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
 ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
 objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
 ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp server ip"
 objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
 ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
 objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
 objMessage.Send
End If
```

I want to know how much it takes to send email and get the status of objMessage.Send in the program.

I want to display the error using Wscript.Echo "error message". What changes are required to the above code so that execution waits until the email has been sent successfully and then display a message.

Thanks in advance.
Ashok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Send` runs synchronously, i.e. it only returns if

- an error occurred
- the SMTP server rejected the message
- the SMTP server accepted the message for delivery

Enable error handling for `Send` and check if an error occurred:

```
On Error Resume Next
objMessage.Send
If Err Then
  WScript.Echo Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description
Else
  WScript.Echo "Success"
End If
On Error Goto 0
```